# Convert a time with 24 format to 12 format

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a time in 24 format in string for example @"22:00" I want to convert this time to be @"10:00 pm" so I write the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *date= [df dateFromString:@"22:00"];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:date]);
```

Unfortunately the result is still @"22:00".

[image]

The question is how to convert a time with 24 format to 12 format?

Comment: Your code is perfect : getting 10:00 PM

Comment: I edit the post with a snapshot for the result.

Comment: You can never get 22:00 because you have changed the format as `hh:mm a`

Comment: You are right guys. I copy the code to a new project and the result is 10:00 PM. I don't know what is wrong with my current project. Is it bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `NSDateFormatter` for that, as it's a simple maths problem:

```
NSString *time24 = @"24:00";
NSArray *elements = [time24 componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSAssert([elements count] == 2, @"Expected 2 time elements"];
NSInteger hour = [elements[0] intValue];
NSInteger minutes = [elements[1] intValue];
NSString *time12 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d %@",
    hour % 12, minutes, (hour >= 12 ? @"PM" : @"AM")];
```

Comment: To avoid hour be 00:00 AM, put this code (hour%12==0 ? 12 : hour%12)